# Dask using too much memory when reading parquet

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, parquet, dask-dataframe

I have a rather large parquet file (~1.35Gb) that I'm trying to read. I'm using Google Colab Pro which gives me 25 Gb of RAM. I ran the following code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
data = dd.read_parquet(DATA_DIR / 'train.parquet', chunksize=100)
data.head()
```

And ran out of memory, is there something I can do to improve the memory consumption? I tried different chunk sizes, as well as removing it entirely, but all run out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

[Docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.read_parquet.html) warn that `chunksize` will be deprecated. Moreover, the value you provided is rather small (this is interpreted to be a bytes value), which will result in too many partitions. Without a reproducible example it's hard to be more specific, but I would recommend using the default settings:

```py
from dask.dataframe import read_parquet
data = read_parquet(DATA_DIR / 'train.parquet')
data.head()  # hopefully works
```

As suggested by @MichaelDelgado, if the parquet file has more than one row_group, it's possible to use `split_row_groups=True` to have smaller partitions:

```py
from dask.dataframe import read_parquet
data = read_parquet(DATA_DIR / 'train.parquet', split_row_groups=True)
data.head()  # hopefully works
```

Comment: I tried with larger chunk sizes as well as removing it entirely, all run all of memory unfortunately

Comment: Hmm, do you have access to the person that created these files? Might be worth saving them with a different `row_group_size`, so each row group is small enough to fit into memory.

Comment: Maybe try with `split_row_groups=True`?

Comment: Took longer but still ran out of memory :(